# Proof on diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L} (\mathbb{R^5})$ is defined by
$$T(x_1,\dots,x_5) = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
Proof if T is diagonalizable.

**Proof:**

$$T(x_1,\dots,x_5) = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
$$\lambda x_1 = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
$$\lambda x_2 = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
$$\lambda x_3 = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
$$\lambda x_4 = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$
$$\lambda x_5 = (x_1+\dots+x_5,\dots,x_1+\dots+x_5)$$

Hence $\lambda = 0$ and $x_1 = \dots = x_n \implies \lambda = n$

Hence $n = \lambda = 5$ and $\lambda = 0$ be the two eigenvalue of T.Let $\lambda = 5$ correspond to vector $(1,1,1,1,1)$ and let $\lambda = 0$ is just the null space of T, and it is spanned by the four vectors $(1,−1,0,0,0,),(1,0,−1,0,0), (1,0,0,−1,0)$ and $(1,0,0,0,−1)$. We can show that these four vectors are linearly independent, so this eigenspace contains 4 linearly independent vectors.  Hence there are a total of five linearly independent eigenvectors, and henceTis diagonalizable.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You wanted to write $\lambda=5$ in the first line of the proof. Else it's basically ok: you found an eigenspace decomposition of $\Bbb R^5$.

Comment: @Berci Hey, just want to ask why we need to pick $\lambda = 5$ as one of my eigenvalue?

Comment: It's not *picking* the eigenvalues, it's that the eigenvalues of $T$ *are* $0$ and $5$. Calculate $T(1,1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Berci I'm not sure if I did it right or wrong. Could you help me out please? Thank you

Comment: What did you do right or wrong? What did you get for $T(1,1,1,1,1)$?

Comment: @Berci I have added my proof to the question

Comment: The right hand sides should be the single components, not the whole vector. Writing $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=5$ makes no sense, these should be the same value in all 5 equations, and $5$ as eigenvalue has multiplicity $1$, while $0$ has $4$, as the nullspace is $4$ dimensional. I still don't see the result of putting $x_1=\cdots=x_5=1$ to obtain $T(1,1,1,1,1)$..

Comment: @Berci I have edited

Comment: Edit it more. Please consider *all* my points in my last comment..

Comment: @Berci I think it look pretty good to me

Comment: Ok. Do you understand why is the eigenvalue $5$ (and not, say, $3$?)

Comment: @Berci Yes sir!

Comment: And, what is $T(1,1,1,1,1)$?

Comment: $T(1,1,1,1,1) = (5,5,5,5,5) ?$

Comment: Yes yes, thank you. That's why $5$ is the eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you!